# Popup with overlay, popup fill window?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

Would like to use a popup(jquery mobile) with content and make it fill the screen. Also with overlay.

Like this, scroll down to bottom, Overlay set to A button.

http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

But I want the popup to fill almost the entire screen. This should act as a new page but be filled with ajax content, I will fix this later...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile will not size a popup or dialog larger than needed to contain the rendered content. If you really want to fill the page, go with a new page. Consider transitioning to a new page with a pop transition instead.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

You might also consider a `dialog` as it obscures the underlying page content

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html

Comment: Can I somehow load ajax to this new page, or will it do an ajax call on its own, if a page is supplied? In that case we could hava a aspx page to serve content.